# Recyclerview not getting updated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update the recyclerview using `notifyDataSetChanged()` but the recyclerview is not getting updated,i know there is lot of similar questions being asked on stack overflow & I tried most of them but nothing seems to work in my case;

First time when data comes into the fragment I'm creating an object for the adapter & setting it to the recyclerview that works well, but next time  when adapter is already initialised i'm trying to notify the adapter that gives me an empty recyclerview even though the supplied list is not empty.

Please suggest.

**RecyclerView Code**

```
 private void showStateList(List<State> states) {
        if (states != null) {
            this.lstStates = states;
            if(stateAdapter == null){
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                stateFragmentBinding.stateRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

                stateFragmentBinding.stateRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(stateFragmentBinding.stateRecyclerView.getContext(),
                        linearLayoutManager.getOrientation()));
                stateFragmentBinding.stateRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

                stateAdapter = new StateAdapter(lstStates, this);
                stateFragmentBinding.stateRecyclerView.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
            }
            else{
                stateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(lstStates);
            }
        }

    }
```

**Adapter Code:**

```
   class StateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StateViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private StateClickListener stateClickListener;
    private List<State> lstStateItem;

    public StateAdapter(List<State> lstStateItem, StateClickListener stateClickListener) {
        this.lstStateItem = lstStateItem;
        this.stateClickListener = stateClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StateViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        StateAdapterBinding stateAdapterBinding = StateAdapterBinding.inflate(inflater, viewGroup, false);
        return new StateViewHolder(stateAdapterBinding, stateClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StateViewHolder stateViewHolder, int position) {
        State state = lstStateItem.get(position);
        stateViewHolder.bind(state, position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lstStateItem.size();
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged(List<State> states) {
        List<State> tempList = new ArrayList<>(states);
        lstStateItem.clear();
        lstStateItem.addAll(tempList);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**ViewHolder class**

```
 class StateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private StateAdapterBinding stateAdapterBinding;
    private StateClickListener stateClickListener;

    StateViewHolder(StateAdapterBinding stateAdapterBinding, StateClickListener stateClickListener) {
        super(stateAdapterBinding.getRoot());
        this.stateAdapterBinding = stateAdapterBinding;
        this.stateClickListener = stateClickListener;
    }

    public void bind(State state, int position) {
        stateAdapterBinding.executePendingBindings();
        stateAdapterBinding.setStateModel(state);
        stateAdapterBinding.setStateHandler(stateClickListener);
        stateAdapterBinding.getRoot().setTag(R.id.lnrHome, position);
        stateAdapterBinding.getRoot().setTag(state);
    }
```

Comment: Post full code of your adapter.

Comment: The question is not complete.. Post your adapter code...

Comment: Posted full adaper code @Kannan_SJD

Comment: Posted full adaper code @DeepPatel

Comment: @Praneshsaw : check my answer and try it

Comment: This code should work.. I just wonder why you are creating a new List<State> tempList, why cant you just add the argument list  to your existing lstStateItem ?

Comment: @Kannan_SJD i agree,but as i'm facing this issue i thought i can create tempory List & give it a try.

Comment: I think removing that wont help either

Comment: Can you explain the second paragraph, can't understand what you want to convey, just create a new instance of adapter, set the adapter and notify it

Comment: I think you should call..  YOUR_BINDING.executePendingBindings()

Comment: Please post StateViewHolder Code

Comment: Posted @DeepPatel

Comment: had you tried step by step debugging while updating data? Put a debug point and check whether proper data is being passed or not.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this : change your data updation method name to **updateDataSet** and give it a try

**RecyclerView Code:**

```
private void showStateList(List<State> states) {
        if (states != null) {
            this.lstStates = states;
            if (stateAdapter == null) {
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                stateFragmentBinding.stateRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

                stateFragmentBinding.stateRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(stateFragmentBinding.stateRecyclerView.getContext(),
                        linearLayoutManager.getOrientation()));
                stateFragmentBinding.stateRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

                stateAdapter = new StateAdapter(lstStates, this);
                stateFragmentBinding.stateRecyclerView.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
            } else {
                stateAdapter.updateDataSet(lstStates);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Adapter Code:**

```
class StateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StateViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private StateClickListener stateClickListener;
    private List<State> lstStateItem = new ArrayList<>();;

    public StateAdapter(List<State> lstStateItem, StateClickListener stateClickListener) {
        this.lstStateItem.addAll(lstStateItem);
        this.stateClickListener = stateClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StateViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        StateAdapterBinding stateAdapterBinding = StateAdapterBinding.inflate(inflater, viewGroup, false);
        return new StateViewHolder(stateAdapterBinding, stateClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StateViewHolder stateViewHolder, int position) {
        State state = lstStateItem.get(position);
        stateViewHolder.bind(state, position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lstStateItem.size();
    }

    public void updateDataSet(List<State> states) {
        this.lstStateItem.clear();
        this.lstStateItem.addAll(states);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**View Holder Code:**

```
class StateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private StateAdapterBinding stateAdapterBinding;
    private StateClickListener stateClickListener;

    StateViewHolder(StateAdapterBinding stateAdapterBinding, StateClickListener stateClickListener) {
        super(stateAdapterBinding.getRoot());
        this.stateAdapterBinding = stateAdapterBinding;
        this.stateClickListener = stateClickListener;
    }

    public void bind(State state, int position) {
        stateAdapterBinding.setStateModel(state);
        stateAdapterBinding.setStateHandler(stateClickListener);
        stateAdapterBinding.getRoot().setTag(R.id.lnrHome, position);
        stateAdapterBinding.getRoot().setTag(state);
        stateAdapterBinding.executePendingBindings();
    }
```

Comment: Tried but similar issue!!

Comment: please check now

Comment: give this a last try. everything else looks fine. if still its not working, you must have to go for step by step debug to check where the data is getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
 your_binding_instance.executePendingBindings()
```

Your viewholder class should look something like this:

```
    class ViewHolder(binding) extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
    bind(item){
    bindnig.item = item
    binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

Comment: since you use databinding.. I think forcing the recyclerview to execute the pending bindings once the list has been updated is important!

Comment: I have given stateAdapterBinding.executePendingBindings(); in onCreateViewHolder but not able to fixed the issue.

Comment: Where have you called this?

Comment: Inside the adapter;i guess i have to call it in my View ie Fragment

Comment: No its inside adapter.. you are correct.. In which part of adapter have you called this? Dyou call it inside bind method of your ViewHolder Class? Or in your notifydatasetchanged method?

Comment: In OnCreateViewHolder after  this line StateAdapterBinding stateAdapterBinding = StateAdapterBinding.inflate(inflater, viewGroup, false);

Comment: can you try calling it inside the bind method? 
look updated answer

Comment: I have tried adding inside View holder class,please check the updated ViewHolder class @Kannan_SJD

Comment: Everything looks fine.. but the executependingbindings should be the last thing to call in bind method

Comment: the recyclerview click calls another fragment & once doing some operation over there i getting back the calling fragment from the backstack and passing the List to notifyDataSetChanged (thats the entire process)

Comment: No..i tried to change the showStateList() method & it starts working don't know how...just figuring it out...

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the showStateList method by below code,if anyone having better solution kindly post:

```
   private void showStateList(List<State> states) {
    if (states != null) {
        this.lstStates = states;
        if(stateAdapter == null){
            stateAdapter = new StateAdapter(lstStates, this);
        }
        else {
            stateAdapter.notifyStateChanged(lstStates);
        }
        stateFragmentBinding.stateRecyclerView.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Need to set adapter everytime...any other solution will be greatly appreciated.